# Resize iframe after adding in on load

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, frame

I'm having trouble resizing an iframe after injecting it on load using javascript. I use a set width of around 300px which works fine but dynamically size the iframe's height to the size of it's content (a blog post).

I've tried getting contentWindow (had no child dom elements) and contentDocument (which was undefined) to no avail.

I do this on load:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
iframe.setAttribute('id','postFrame'); 
iframe.setAttribute('frameborder','no'); 
iframe.setAttribute('scrolling','no'); 
iframe.setAttribute('onload','resizeFrame();'); 
iframe.setAttribute('width','300px'); 
iframe.setAttribute('src','http://espn.go.com/espn/print?id=7454651'); 
var container = document.getElementById('container'); 
container.appendChild(iframe);


function resizeFrame(){ /* resize iframe based on content height*/ }
```

Is there a way to re size iframe height based on content within the iframe?

*EDIT**

Possible workaround:

Is there any hope that i could use Access-Control-Allow-Origin to assist the problem? Lets say the page that goes in the iframe is my own or is echo'd from a php script

Comment: I assume you don't own 'espn.go.com', in which case I have done a lot of work in this area at work in the several months - it relies on co-operation between the 'customer' and 'supplier' (you would be one of them, espn.go.com would be the other). I think it best if you contact me privately so I can talk you through it on Skype. If you leave your Skype username on here then I will add you and will try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following function to resize an iframe to be the height of the content. It's for an intranet app (and only properly tested in IE8) but certainly works so it might provide the missing clue-

```
function sizeIframeToContent(id) {
    // resize iframe to be the height of the content
    try {
        var frame = document.getElementById(id);
        innerDoc = (frame.contentDocument) ?
                   frame.contentDocument : frame.contentWindow.document;
        var objToResize = (frame.style) ? frame.style : frame;
        objToResize.height = innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 10 + 'px';
        //objToResize.width = innerDoc.body.scrollWidth + 10 + 'px';
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}
```

**Edit**  an explanation- once the document has loaded you should be able to find the document height which you can then use as the height for the iframe. I commented the width part of the above function as you're specifically asking about the height.

Comment: I get this in console: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Comment: @buffstar24 getting that in Chrome as well...will see what I can do

Comment: And in firefox i get Permission denied for <mysite> to get property HTMLDocument.body

Comment: @buffstar24 I think it's a permission issue locally. Using the Chrome developer tools and stepping in you can see the properties but it isn't giving access...

Comment: @buffstar24 I used the Visual Studio web server to run the code and it worked fine...but it wouldn't work in Chrome when not running through a web server

Comment: This is why I said about using Skype - it's rather complicated. It's due to XSS. You need to set up a subdomain which is pointing to their server, get them to set the document.domain value to, say, abc.com (assuming your site is www.abc.com) and do the same yourself. This way the browser sees the iFrame and the main site as being on the same domain. You can then access any elements in the iFrame and in theory the above code will then work.

Comment: Is there any hope that i could use Access-Control-Allow-Origin to assist the problem? Lets say the page that goes in the iframe is my own or is echo'd from a php script

Comment: @buffstar24 I'm not sure. If it were you're own page you'd have no trouble accessing the document in the iframe...If it were echo'd kind of like a proxy it should be ok because it will be your page. The original pages javascript may not work however...